# Significant overhead while using OpenVPN

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn

I bought myself a perfect privacy subscription and tested several servers. While downloading

some test files, I recognized, that the VPN Client used nearly 3/4 of my available upload speed.

Some info:

- Service: Perfect Privacy
- Connection Speed: 11/1 Mbit - IPv4
- Client: OpenVPN

I did some additional tests, by downloading the same file (Ubuntu iso over http ), the download speed was always the same ( ~ 1.1 MB/s ) , but the upload usage differs significantly:

- No VPN:
  [Normal upload usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzeOE.jpg)
- iOS VPN (IkeV2)
  [More upload usage, but not as much as openvpn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vEkm.jpg)
- OpenVPN
  [high upload usage with openvpn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5cpY.jpg)

Is it just the nature of the OpenVPN protocol, that the upload overhead is so monstrous?

I tried OpenVPN in tcp and udp mode on multiple machines, with always the same results, so maybe my config file has errors or needs some tuning.

I already played around with the mtu values, but with no luck so far.

Do you have any advice?

I am using the standard configuration file of perfect privacy:

```
proto udp
tun-mtu 1500
mssfix 1500
fragment 1500
cipher AES-256-CBC 
ignore-unknown-option ncp-disable # ovpn 2.3 to 2.4 transition
ncp-disable

#Server urls ....

auth SHA512
auth-user-pass
client
comp-lzo
dev tun
#float
hand-window 120
inactive 604800
mute-replay-warnings
nobind
#ns-cert-type server  # deprecated in openvpn 2.5
remote-cert-tls server # new
persist-key
persist-remote-ip
persist-tun
ping 5
ping-restart 120
redirect-gateway def1
remote-random
reneg-sec 3600
resolv-retry 60
route-delay 2
route-method exe
script-security 2
tls-cipher 
TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-CAMELLIA-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-RSA-WITH-CAMELLIA-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CB$
tls-timeout 5
verb 4
tun-ipv6

#certs
```

Comment: I don't see why it should use that much up bandwidth, unless it has to continously change the encryption keys for some reason. Or the download gets stuck due to bufferbloat, and the retransmission requests pile up. Debug with `wireshark` on both the `tun` and the external interface to understand what is really going on. Also try an unencrypted OpenVPN connection, if you can.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, I played a bit around with the encryption methods, and it seems that it really had something to do with that, I previously used the the AES CBC-Mode, after switching to AES-GCM, the upload usage was down to normal. I will definetly do some reading on that, to find out what could cause problems with CBC. Thank you for your suggestions.